# How do you connect to a server and login trough console in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket

So lets say I want to connect to a website and I want to login to the website without accessing it using a search engine. Can someone tell me how I should do that and what libraries to use using C++? Thanks.

Comment: That very much depends on the website and what login mechanisms it uses

Comment: I would suggest you start your research around http and https and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.e. if you want to log into your gmail, you'll need Gmail's login API from their website.

Try and look in the communications sections of this website to find what you need :
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Once you've downloaded the most suitable library for you, do these steps:

1. Make sure you have a valid internet / ethernet connection,
2. Find the exact API call to login to the account,
3. Make sure you have the correct authorisation to log into the account.
4. You're connected.

Comment: Look for anything with "rest" / "restful api" that suits your needs.

Comment: Hello! I fond the following libraries: restc-cpp, restbed, restful_mapper and rest_rpc. Could you tell me which one you are referring to?Thanks.

Comment: I think "C++ REST SDK" is the better options for what you're looking for.